# One off introduction page using JavaScript for iphone app

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm trying to include a one-off introductory page using JavaScript before index.html to introduce the purpose of the app and addressing the issues that we face.

The page will be in front of index.page something like a full page pop up of introductory page. It'll only appear once every 20 visits? If there such a thing that can be done on JS. It is for iPhone app as Hybrid (HTML5, CSS3 and JS using Cordova 2.1 formerly Phonegap). I think there is?

Comment: Count how many visits using `window.localStorage` and if it `% 20 === 0` display whatever you want.

Comment: Is it that using JavaScript? Can I have a full JavsScript so I can understand better, please.

Comment: I didn't know that you can use cookies in iPhone app? It is not web app. Yes, I would use cookies for web app. BUT, this is native app from Xcode using HTML5, CSS3 & JS as well as Cordova 2.1 Framework (formerly Phonegap).

Comment: @ Paul S. Is this window.localStorage for web app or the native app using Cordova 2.1 (formerly Phonegap). I'm using native app (xcode and cordova).

Answer (score 1):

Try using JavaScript local storage.

```
window.onload = function(){
     if( localStorage.seenIntro ){
         // Display Normal Page (user has seen intro)
     }else{
         localStorage.seenIntro = true;
         // Display Intro Screen
     }
}
```

This will check to see if a localStorage value is defined, if it is the user has seen the page before and it will load the normal web page. Otherwise it will create the localStorage value and show the intro screen.

Comment: That is brilliant. Is this for "introduction page" before index.html to show screen introduction. Not the one with a launch or splash page as default when opening the app.

Comment: I would put is on the normal index page and redirect the user to the intro screen using window.location as this would avoid loading the intro page each time. However you could do it either way round.

Comment: I understand, thank you. For example, how do I use seenIntro.png or <div id='intro'> apart from JS in a header section? How does that work to recognize the intro page?

Comment: 1. Give the <div id="intro"> a css style of 'display: none;', 2. Replace '// Display Intro Screen' with 'document.getElementById("intro").style.display = "block";'